# Jquery and CSS background change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem with the following line:

```
document.getElementById("giftcard").getElementsByTagName("label").style.backgroundImage ="url(giftcard_icon-d.jpg)";
```

I am trying to change background image after clicking a `label`.

I do have 5 `label`s in a page, but when i click on `label`, the background should change it. Other labels should be reset to use this `giftcard_icon-d.jpg` image as their background.

How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#giftcard label').click(function() {
       document.getElementById("giftcard").getElementsByTagName("label").style.backgroundImage ="url(giftcard_icon-d.jpg)";
       this.style.backgroundImage ="url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)";      
});
```

Comment: What is happening exactly? Background changes for none of them???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, this ought to do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#giftcard label').click(function() {
        $("#giftcard label").css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)");
    });
});
```

But it also depends on whether the ID is correct, a label is present and that the image URL is valid.

For multiple `label`'s you should be OK with a selector:

```
$("#giftcard > label").css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)");
```

To update after concluding exactly what it was you wanted:

```
$('#giftcard label').click(function() {
    $("#giftcard label").css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-d.jpg)");
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)");        
});
```

Comment: Perfect! it works now. 
I used this way : '$('#giftcard label').click(function() {
    $("#giftcard label").css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-d.jpg)");
      this.style.backgroundImage ="url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)";
  
   
 
});  '

Comment: Yeah, I worked out properly what you wanted after I posted - I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your mixing vanilla javascript and jquery here, seems a bit silly. If you want to alter the other labels to "reset" them you can do something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#giftcard').delegate('label', 'click', function() {

    $(this).css('background', 'url(giftcard_icon-d.jpg)');

    $('#giftcard > label').not(this)
     .css('background', 'url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)');

  }); 

});
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/GUFtx/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly this should do the trick

```
$(function() {
    $('#giftcard label').click(function() {
        $('#giftcard label').css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-d.jpg)");
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(giftcard_icon-a.jpg)");
    });
});
```

working sample
http://jsfiddle.net/FvNdR/

Comment: @XML guy I Guess your doubt was just on how to set the style properties on jquery, when @Mr. Disappointment posted his answer you got the idea and solved by yourself.